# How do I get the last non-empty line of a file using tail in Bash?

Tags: bash, line, tail

How do I get the last non-empty line using `tail` under Bash shell?

For example, `my_file.txt` looks like this:

> hello
>   hola
>   bonjour
>   (empty line)
>   (empty line)

Obviously, if I do `tail -n 1 my_file.txt` I will get an empty line. In my case I want to get `bonjour`. How do I do that?

Comment: what if you have spaces/tabs at the end of file?

Comment: @ghostdog74 great solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/2641745/658497

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use Awk:

```
awk '/./{line=$0} END{print line}' my_file.txt
```

This solution has the advantage of using just one tool.

Comment: Downside: Needs to read the WHOLE file, and assign EACH LINE to awk variables -> This can be quite CPU and IO intensive.

Comment: Yes, the solution is simple, but far from being efficient. An efficient solution would open the file, seek to the end and scan backward.

Answer (score 39):

Use tac, so you dont have to read the whole file:

```
tac FILE |egrep -m 1 .
```

Comment: @vault not on Sierra, 2016.

Comment: @gsamaras try swiping from right to left on the touchbar 

Comment: Then the error that `gtac` is not found won't be shown @vault . . . ;)

Comment: @gsamaras the touchbar is also lick-able . And, by the way, this worked for me on CEntOS 7.5 (vagrant box `bento/centos-7.5`).

Comment: Why use `egrep` instead of `grep`? There is nothing "extended"  in the regular expression.

Comment: Besides `egrep` is deprecated according to the manual page of `grep` nowadays.

Answer (score 26):

How about using `grep` to filter out the blank lines first?

```
$ cat rjh
1
2
3


$ grep "." rjh | tail -1
3
```

Comment: or, instead of 'cat rjh | grep "." | tail -1', use 'grep . rjh | tail -1'

Comment: could someone explain the grep "." part ?

Comment: In `grep "."`, that period is regex, meaning "any character".  In regex a blank line has a beginning (^), an end ($ or \n), but nothing in the middle, so grepping for the period only returns lines that contain characters.  E.g., not blank.

Comment: Simple > efficient. Bonus:  `... | grep \. | tail -1`  one char shorter!

Answer (score 6):

Instead of `tac` you can use `tail -r` if available.

```
tail -r | grep -m 1 '.'
```

Comment: Which versions of `tail(1)` have the `-r` option? The one in GNU coreutils doesn't have it, cf. http://debbugs.gnu.org/18808

Comment: The issue with this solution is that if the file you're scanning is a shell script file then it will only filter the echo output rather than the actual file contents, try 1) creating a script file with a few simple echo commands; 2) pasting the full file path into the console and entering " | tail -1" at the end; notice that it will only output your last echo command's output rather than the entire echo command...

Answer (score 4):

if you want to omit any whitespaces, ie, spaces/tabs at the end of the line, not just empty lines

```
awk 'NF{p=$0}END{print p}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

If `tail -r` isn't available and you don't have `egrep`, the following works nicely:

`tac $FILE | grep -m 1 '.'`

As you can see, it's a combination of two of the previous answers.

Comment: `egrep` is the same as `grep` just instead of needing to put `... | grep "my[regex]Expr"` you only need to put `... | egrep my[regexExpr]` it's a little more complex that that as you may run into a syntax issue, however a few escape characters should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I had problems using other solutions, so I made this.

First, get last 25 lines, assuming at least 1 is not empty. Filter out empty lines, and print out the last line.

```
 tail -n25 file.txt | grep -v "^.$" | tail -n 1
```

One major advantage this has, you can show more than 1 line, just by changing the last 1 to, lets say, 5. Also, it only reads last 25 lines of the file.

If you have huge amounts of empty lines, you might want to change the 25 to something bigger, repeating until it works.

Answer (score 0):

Print the last non-empty line that does not contain only tabs and spaces like this:

```
tac my_file.txt | grep -m 1 '[^[:blank:]]'
```

Note that Grep supports POSIX character class `[:blank:]` even if it is not documented in its manual page until [2020-01-01](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/commit/doc/grep.in.1?id=3ab01fbbb0465d78e9eb9d11a5325354f24ab9bb).

File may contain other non-visible characters, so maybe using `[:space:]` may be better in some cases. All space is not covered even by that, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode).

Comment: If you want to add more lines, change the number after `-m` and add `|tac` to the end to get it back in correct order

Answer (score 0):

Using [ag](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) way:

```
cat file.txt | ag "\S" | tail -1
```